# CSS Align floating navbar

Tags: css, tumblr

So I've got an [example of what is the header on my Tumblr Page](http://jsfiddle.net/qTPec/).
I don't know why I'm having so much trouble doing this, but I can't figure it out.

I've got a `<ul>` floating-left navbar, whose parent container has a width of 50%. I need these items to be centered below the main text, but because they float left, this is hard to accomplish.

```
<nav id="mainNav">  
    <ul>            
        <li><a href="/ask">Ask</a></li>                  
        <li><a href="/archive">Archive</a></li>
        <li><a href="/random">Random</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://skwh.tumblr.com/rss">RSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" id="btnSearch">Search</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/SomekidwithHTML">Twitter</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
header #mainNav {
    width:auto;
    margin:auto;
}
header #mainNav ul {
    height:30px;
    width:auto;
}
header #mainNav ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:2;
    background-color:#1BA300;
    border:2px solid black;
}
header #mainNav ul li:hover {
    background-color:black;   
} 
header #mainNav ul li a {
    color:#00FF00;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
}
```

I need these items to center under the main text, but nothing i've tried works. What am I doing wrong? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to center a `block` element you need `margin:0 auto` but to achieve this you need to set a fixed with for the `block` element. So for your `header #mainNav` add {width:372px}` and will be ok.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qTPec/2/

Another solution is to add `display:inline-block` for `header #mainNav`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qTPec/3/

Answer (score 0):

try `display: inline-block` instead of the `float`. That way you can center it.

http://jsfiddle.net/qTPec/1/